# Convert imagesource to string

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, imagesource

I have this code:

```
if (MyImage.Source == "ms-appx:///Assets/myimage.png")
{
   //do something
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'
```

So how could I convert imagesource to string so I can compare them? I tried `ToString()` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Image is binded to a string property of a class named Picture.
I have this in XAML <Image x:Name="MyImage" Margin="225,21,0,0" Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50" Tapped="MyImage_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
Image is binded to a property of a class

Comment: For starters you need `==` instead of `=` for comparison.

Comment: ye you are right I didn't notice when I was writing the post.

Comment: I wrote string property :P

Answer (score 0):

Instead use like this below.

```
Dim Cnvr As New ImageSourceConverter
Dim SrcImgUrl As String = Cnvr.ConvertToInvariantString(CurrentImage.Source)
If SrcImgUrl.Trim.Length > 0 AndAlso StringCompare(SrcImgUrl, imgUri.Url.ToString,StringComparer.Text)=0 then
...
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

The image's `Source` property is an `ImageSource` type, not a string.

As per the [documentation for `ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx):

> An object that represents the image source file for the drawn image. Typically you set this with a BitmapImage object, constructed with the URI that describes the path to a valid image source file. Or, you can initialize a BitmapSource with a stream, perhaps a stream from a storage file.

[Updated:]
Therefore, you need to do two things: 
1. Determine the type of the image source
2. If it's a `BitmapImage`, check the bitmap's `UriSource` with the expected URI:

```
var imgUri = new Uri("ms:app:///Assets/SplashScreen.scale-100.png");
img.Source = new BitmapImage(imgUri);

if (img.Source.GetType() == typeof(BitmapImage)
    && (img.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource.Equals(imgUri))
{
    // Do something useful here!

}
```

HTH.

Comment: I know that. I don't want to change the image. I just want to see if the old image path is same with "ms-appx:///Assets/myimage.png".

Comment: img.Source is of BitmapFrameDecode type which is not BitmapImage.  (WPF)